# AngularJS - how to calculate input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm looking for a good way to preform a calculation on a couple of inputs and store the total value in a `$scope` variable as well as a total field (disable).

Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18830/

In this case we need to apply `unique visit / mobile visit = total visit`, store the total in `metricData.totalVisit`, and set the value of the disabled field to that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides `$watch` to do stuff like this. You can simply do something like:

```
$scope.$watch('metricData', function(metricData) {
    metricData.totalVisit = metricData.uniqueVisit / metricData.mobileVisit;
}, true);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j0ajrtzr/

(note this is just an example to demo basic functionality, more info at [$scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch))